# The database page in firebase in not showing my database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-assistant

After connecting new app from android studio to realtime database, the database page in firebase is not showing my database.Below are some links of screen shots of my android studio and database page of firebase console.

This is the Firebase image

[image]

This is my code with proof of connection

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On this page, "Database" refers to both, Firestore and Realtime Database.

You have to click `Create database`, where it reads: `Or choose Realtime Database`.

Comment: I had created it many times ,it gets enable in firebase but whenever i refresh or login to firebase it gets disable and tells to create database

Comment: @KrishnaSalampuriya try to clear the browser cache once; or contact their support, if you think there's something stuck.